# How do I add another tag to be parsed as embedded JS in a tmLanguage file?

Tags: javascript, textmate, taglib, sublimetext

#### Back Story (not really important but it frames the question)

I have a TagLib in a JSP that takes its contents and wraps its containing code in a script block (it does much more but for the sake of the question it is not important). For example:

```
<aui:script use="some-module">
    //my code
</aui:script>
```

will be served as

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    AUI().use('sub-module', function(A) {
        // my code
    }
</script>
```

#### The Question

I would like all the code in between `<aui:script use="things"></aui:script>` and to have JavaScript syntax highlighting. So I tried editing the `HTML.tmLanguage` file to include this but Sublime Text 2 throws a fit.

Admittedly my regex knowledge is poor.

How can I edit `HTML.tmLanguage` to include my `<aui:script />` taglib?

Site note, the taglib accepts various attributes like `use` and `position`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have so much trouble with the regex rules but I managed to get it somewhat working using the normal  rules. I should add that this is a new block, along with the regular one.

```
{
    name = 'source.js.embedded.html';
    begin = '(?:^\s+)?(<)((?i:(aui[\:]script)))\b(?![^>]*/>)';
    end = '(?<=</(aui[\:]script))(>)(?:\s*\n)?';
    beginCaptures = {
        1 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.tag.html'; };
        2 = { name = 'entity.name.tag.script.html'; };
    };
    endCaptures = {
        2 = {
            name = 'punctuation.definition.tag.html';
        };
    };
    patterns = (
        {
            include = '#tag-stuff';
        },
        {
            begin = '(?<!</(?:aui[\:]script))(>)';
            end = '(</)((?i:aui[\:]script))';
            captures = {
                1 = {
                    name = 'punctuation.definition.tag.html';
                };
                2 = {
                    name = 'entity.name.tag.script.html';
                };
            };
            patterns = (
                {   name = 'comment.line.double-slash.js';
                    match = '(//).*?((?=</(aui[\:]script))|$\n?)';
                    captures = {
                        1 = {
                            name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.js';
                        };
                    };
                },
                {
                    name = 'comment.block.js';
                    begin = '/\*';
                    end = '\*/|(?=</(aui[\:]script))';
                    captures = {
                        0 = {
                            name = 'punctuation.definition.comment.js';
                        };
                    };
                },
                {
                    include = '#php';
                },
                {
                    include = 'source.js';
                },
            );
        },
    );
}
```

**XML Format**

```
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:(aui[\:]script)))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)</string>
    <key>beginCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>punctuation.definition.tag.html</string>
        </dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>entity.name.tag.script.html</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>end</key>
    <string>(?&lt;=&lt;/(aui[\:]script))(&gt;)(?:\s*\n)?</string>
    <key>endCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>punctuation.definition.tag.html</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>source.js.embedded.html</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>#tag-stuff</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>begin</key>
            <string>(?&lt;!&lt;/(?:aui[\:]script))(&gt;)</string>
            <key>captures</key>
            <dict>
                <key>1</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>punctuation.definition.tag.html</string>
                </dict>
                <key>2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>entity.name.tag.script.html</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>end</key>
            <string>(&lt;/)((?i:aui[\:]script))</string>
            <key>patterns</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>captures</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>1</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>name</key>
                            <string>punctuation.definition.comment.js</string>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <key>match</key>
                    <string>(//).*?((?=&lt;/(aui[\:]script))|$\n?)</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>comment.line.double-slash.js</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>begin</key>
                    <string>/\*</string>
                    <key>captures</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>name</key>
                            <string>punctuation.definition.comment.js</string>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <key>end</key>
                    <string>\*/|(?=&lt;/(aui[\:]script))</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>comment.block.js</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>#php</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>source.js</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: I've also added an XML version for those who need it in that format.

Comment: what do you mean by "this is a new block"?  Do you mean that this gets added somewhere in the `HTML.tmLanguage` file?