# Sublime Text 2 syntax highlighting for XML and Java in the same file?

Tags: java, xml, custom-action, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I have a proprietary application that takes XML files and can use embedded Java code in XML file to perform certain operations. I opened the XML file in ST2, but I only get syntax highlighting for XML code, Java code is just white. If I switch the syntax to Java from view menu, java code is properly highlighted. Is there a way to have both languages syntax highlighted in the same file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two links of note:

- [How do I add another tag to be parsed as embedded JS in a tmLanguage file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693272/how-do-i-add-another-tag-to-be-parsed-as-embedded-js-in-a-tmlanguage-file)
- http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/27384-nested-syntax-highlighting/

I've done some embedded syntax work, but nothing as complex as you're describing, so I'm not convinced my work is relevant.